# How to detect mobile device like Zara.com?

Tags: javascript, mobile

I did some research, and am aware of there are 2 ways to detect a mobile website, either by check user-agent, or by screen resolution. Though it seems that zara.com does not use 1 of those 2. For instance, open zara.com with chrome debugger mobile mode would not return mobile site, or "Request desktop site" on iOS would not return desktop site.

So I am really curious, how does Zara do it?

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I used in my projects.

```
function isMobile() {
 try {
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|pocket|psp|kindle|avantgo|blazer|midori|Tablet|Palm|maemo|plucker|phone|BlackBerry|symbian|IEMobile|mobile|ZuneWP7|Windows Phone|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
     return true;
    };
    return false;
 } catch(e){ console.log("Error in isMobile"); return false; }
}
```